# Android import R. only once for several clases

Tags: android, android-resources

I have one master project which i have to compile with three different packagenames (which is declared in the AndroidManifest, the source packagenames won't change). When merging into the the different branches i always get a conflict with the import `org.example.master.R` and i have to change it manually in every class to `org.example.branch1.R`. That takes me about 15 minutes everytime.. Any ideas to declare it only once in the code that i can change it only at one place?

Comment: Write a script to do it for you.  You are a programmer after all.  Its about 6 lines of perl if you're verbose.  You can probably do it with a 1 liner.

Comment: i thought there is maybe a more beautyful solution